# How to show next and previous data on hover in angular 2

Tags: angular, ngroute

I am building a simple angular two app. Everything is working fine. In Project Detail next and previous is working fine when the user clicks it shows next and previous data in the view. But the problem is when I hover the next or previous button it should show me the next or previous data in browser bottom URL.

As in component HTML, i have routerLink so can you just help me what to put so that it should show me the next and previous data.

Here is component nav HTML

```
<div class="prev-btn">
    <a [routerLink]="" (click)="previousProject()" [ngClass]="{disabled: currentProjectIndex === 0}">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Prev</span></a>
  </div>

  <div class="next-btn">
    <a [routerLink]="" (click)="nextProject()" [ngClass]="{disabled: currentProjectIndex === (total-1)}"><span>Next</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
```

and my two methods of next and previous in the component are

```
previousProject(){
this.dataService.getProjects().subscribe(
  (proj: Project[]) => {
    if(this.currentProjectIndex !== 0){
      this.currentProjectIndex = this.currentProjectIndex - 1;
      this.project = proj[this.currentProjectIndex];
    }else{
      this.currentProjectIndex = 0;
      this.project = proj[this.currentProjectIndex];
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/work', proj[this.currentProjectIndex].id]);
  });
```

}

```
nextProject(){
this.dataService.getProjects().subscribe(
  (proj: Project[]) => {
    if(this.currentProjectIndex !== this.total-1){
      this.currentProjectIndex = this.currentProjectIndex + 1;
      this.project = proj[this.currentProjectIndex];
    }else{
      this.project = proj[this.total-1];
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/work', proj[this.currentProjectIndex].id]);
  });
```

}

Comment: You need to add `href` value then it is possible.

Comment: But what value can i call a next and previous method like this [routerLink]="nextProject()"

Comment: you want to navigate to next record or display like tooltip?

Comment: navigating to next and previous is working fine, but  just want to display like tooltip (what will be next project or previous project)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the **(click)** with the **[routerLink]**
And define the **routerLink** with your router and a paramater of `proj[this.currentProjectIndex].id`.

Refer this:

`[routerLink]="['/middle', previousProject.id]"`

and

`[routerLink]="['/middle', nextProject.id]"`

At your component, define the previousProject and nextProject, and value to them according to your business logic in the constructor or ngOnInit.

**Update**

In angular2, navigate to the same router will do nothing. So you can subscribe to changes in the parameters that you send like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    const id = params['id'];
    // create service to get the data by using the changed 'id' parameter
  });
}
```

Comment: If i define my logic inside ngOnInit it will work once then after i click again it will not work

Comment: this is because you are trying to navigate to the active router. check the update to  do with this.